# MSBUILD macro documentation?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I'm using MSBUILD macros in my .csproj files for AfterBuild events mainly just to copy files.  I'm doing this by example, so the only ones I know of are the ones I've seen in use: SolutionDir, ProjectDir, OutputPath, and Configuration.  Is there a list or good info page online anywhere so I can read up on what's available, what point in the build they're available, customization, etc?  I know that when using post build events in the project properties Build Events tab, the macros and their corresponding values are listed in a dialog...does any such gui exist for MSBUILD?  Currently I'm just manually editing the .csproj files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's the [MSDN MSBuild Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx).

The landing page has an overview of the different areas, though I must admit I can't find anything on the AfterBuild events at the moment. Even the [Targets page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171462.aspx) itself is a little short of information in this area.

Comment: Thanks google.  I was kinda hoping for a little bit of discussion to give me some background and maybe a pointer or two before I read the whole book's worth of documentation online.

Comment: Fair enough...documentation is horrendous in this area.  Hopefully there's a book on Amazon with better and more complete documentation.  Thx

Answer (score 16):

These are called Properties, not macros. See:

[Reserved Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx)

[Common project properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx)

Comment: If you read these pages you'll actually notice that `SolutionDir` and `ProjectDir` (e.g.) are not mentioned at all there...

Answer (score 6):

Here is what you were looking for.

[MSDN - Macros for Build Commands and Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  I posted this about 2 1/2 yrs ago, but your answer is good for people googling it in the future